# add <meta> tag to editor in prestashop 1.6

Tags: javascript, php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6

I want to add this code to my editor:

```
<div itemprop="video" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/VideoObject">
<h2 itemprop="name" class="h2tags">new video</h2>
<video width="100%" height="auto" title="new video" class="videotag" 
controls="controls">
</video>
<meta itemprop="thumbnailUrl" 
content="https://abzarline.arvanvod.com/xb6O7bWLJ3/kGg1XAybJo/thumbnail.png" />
<meta itemprop="uploadDate" content="2019-10-17" />
<meta itemprop="description" content="new vid des" />
</div>
```

When i add this code and click on ok then meta tags and some other attributes are gone.

What can in do for this case?

I want to add schema tags for my videos.

For more info about structured data read this article:

https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/video#video-object

Answer (score 2):

Prestashop clears html

-- Navigate to the Preferences -> General tab

-- Disable Use HTMLPurifier Library

-- Save

Answer (score -1):

Your `<meta>` tags have to be inside the `<head>` tags, like so:

```html
<head>
  <meta></meta>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Title</h2>
  <div>Your content</div>
</body>
```

Some more info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Introduction_to_HTML/The_head_metadata_in_HTML)

Comment: I know that. My meta tags is about videos not my html page. And i want to add this microdata manually for each video.

Comment: classese/Product.php has a cleanHtml validation for description.             'description' =>                array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml'),

Comment: @MahdiShad tnx for comment. i found this line. how i shoud change this line to solve my probleme?

Comment: You can remove validate or change it to isString

Comment: @MahdiShad i do that. but noting happen.